# XSLT: Copy one element (including children) into other node

Tags: xml, xslt

I've searched the whole net, but I've found no solution for my XML transformation problem. I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2016-04-06T10:00:04">
    <studyroot>
        <crocode>AMS</crocode>
        <croname>AMS GmbH</croname>
        <exportdatetime>2016-04-04T10:17:59</exportdatetime>
        <studynumer>STUDYXYZ</studynumer>
        <site>
            <number>005</number>
            <name>Dr. ABC</name>
            <paymentplan>Laboruntersuchung</paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
        <site>
            <number>016</number>
            <name>Dr. XYZ</name>
            <paymentplan>Laboruntersuchung</paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
        <site>
            <number>053</number>
            <name>Dr. DEF</name>
            <patient>01</patient>
            <paymentplan>Laboruntersuchung</paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
    </studyroot>
    <patient>
        <site>053</site>
        <number>01</number>
        <service>Hauptuntersuchung</service>
    </patient>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <pat>01</pat>
        <code>HAU</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Hauptuntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <code>PAR</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <paymentplan>
        <code>LAB</code>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <service>PAR</service>
    </paymentplan>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <pat>01</pat>
        <code>HAU</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Hauptuntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <code>PAR</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
</dataroot>
```

As a first step, I want to substitute the `paymentplan` tag in every site tag with the `paymentplan` tag with parent `dataroot`, if the name tag inside `paymentplan` fits. That's where I'm stuck. Can anyone help me, I'm very new to XSLT? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you show the output you expect in this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy-of` either the current `paymentplan` element or `copy-of` the appropriate `/dataroot/paymentplan` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paymentplan[local-name(..) = 'site']">
  <xsl:variable name="curUntersuchung" select="text()" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/dataroot/paymentplan[name/text() = $curUntersuchung]">
      <xsl:copy-of select="/dataroot/paymentplan[name/text() = $curUntersuchung]" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For replacing the second `Laboruntersuchung` with `Hauptuntersuchung` in the source file this gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2016-04-06T10:00:04">
    <studyroot>
        <crocode>AMS</crocode>
        <croname>AMS GmbH</croname>
        <exportdatetime>2016-04-04T10:17:59</exportdatetime>
        <studynumer>STUDYXYZ</studynumer>
        <site>
            <number>005</number>
            <name>Dr. ABC</name>
            <paymentplan>
                <code>LAB</code>
                <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
                <service>PAR</service>
            </paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
        <site>
            <number>016</number>
            <name>Dr. XYZ</name>
            <paymentplan>Hauptuntersuchung</paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
        <site>
            <number>053</number>
            <name>Dr. DEF</name>
            <patient>01</patient>
            <paymentplan>
                <code>LAB</code>
                <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
                <service>PAR</service>
            </paymentplan>
            <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
        </site>
    </studyroot>
    <patient>
        <site>053</site>
        <number>01</number>
        <service>Hauptuntersuchung</service>
    </patient>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <pat>01</pat>
        <code>HAU</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Hauptuntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <code>PAR</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <paymentplan>
        <code>LAB</code>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <service>PAR</service>
    </paymentplan>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <pat>01</pat>
        <code>HAU</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Hauptuntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
    <service>
        <site>053</site>
        <code>PAR</code>
        <iteration>1</iteration>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <done>0</done>
        <obsolete>0</obsolete>
        <completedate>2016-04-04T00:00:00</completedate>
    </service>
</dataroot>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to tell what you want, as you're not posting your expected output XML. But from your question, I assume that you want to transform

```
<site>
    <number>005</number>
    <name>Dr. ABC</name>
    <paymentplan>Laboruntersuchung</paymentplan>
    <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
</site>
```

to

```
<site>
    <number>005</number>
    <name>Dr. ABC</name>
    <paymentplan>
        <code>LAB</code>
        <name>Laboruntersuchung</name>
        <service>PAR</service>
    </paymentplan>
    <studycode>STUDYXYZ</studycode>
</site>
```

Is that correct?

If so, then your XSL template would be:

```
<xsl:template match="//site/paymentplan">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::dataroot/paymentplan[name=current()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```